# Setting a domain registered with 123Reg to work with Fasthosts virtual servers

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I have a domain registered on 123-Reg which I unlocked and changed the name servers to point to fasthosts ones.

I can't access the domain name in fasthosts control panel unless I transfer the domain (which would cost money) but I cant as I haven't had the domain registered for more than 60 days.

I have setup the correct bindings in IIS7 anyway.

Normally I would choose the domain in the fasthosts control panel and set the a record there but again I cant access that.

I have gotten no support from fasthosts for this, which is sad since their servers are really good.

How can I get this working? Surely I can have a domain registered somewhere and host elsewhere without transfering or incurring more costs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running your server and setting up your virtual host, then you just need to use 123 name servers and edit the DNS configuration for your domain within their control panel, change the @ to your IP address, add a www sub domain name and change this also.

123 offer dedicated servers through Webfusion, so that is another alternative.

Answer (score 0):

It should certainly be possible to have one company provide DNS service for your domain and another company provide web-service for that domain.

For example, 123-Reg ought to be able to provide DNS service for `example.com`. This would involve the `NS` records for `example.com` resolving to the IP-address of a 123-Reg server. Using 123-reg's DNS control panel you should be able to add an `A` record for `www.example.com` that mentions the IP-address of the server owned by Fasthosts that hosts your web-server/service.

Any webserver, including IIS7 ought not to care where the DNS server is located.

I am not familiar with 123-Reg, Fasthosts, or recent versions of IIS - but I'd be surprised if any of them make it impossible to do as I have outlined above.